How to convert "Basic" dyno to "Eco" dyno in Heroku? (I'm subscribed to Eco)
I have two Heroku apps on Basic dynos, one with Postgres addon. I'd like to swap the two running Basic dynos over to the Eco subscription. These are hobby projects and can happily sleep when not getting traffic.
How do I convert these existing Basic dyno apps to Eco?
I have subscribed to Eco on my Heroku billing page. However under resources it doesn't give me the Eco dyno type to change to.
I also cannot seem to submit support tickets, as it says the apps are free? Screenshots below.
Any ideas?







:facepalm:
Only personal apps support eco. I had my apps in a team.
Transferring app ownership back to my user account allowed me to select eco.
